# What is proper JavaScript IPv4 regex excluding 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255?

Tags: javascript, regex, ipv4

Could you guys let me know the proper regex for IPv4 (excluding 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255) in JavaScript language?

Actually, my test regex is as below. But still 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 is matching.

So, is there better regex than mine ? and also any solution to exclude 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255

Thanks in advance.

```
    function inputCheck(inputString) {
        var inputList = inputString.split("\n");
        var flagList = [];
        var ipRegex = new RegExp("^(([1-9]?\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\\d)\\.){3}([1-9]?\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\\d)$");

        for (var i=0; i<inputList.length; i++) {
            var tempResult = ipRegex.test(inputList[i]);
            flagList.push(tempResult);
        }

        if (inputString.replace(/\s/gi, "").length === 0) {
            return true;
        } else if(flagList.indexOf(false) !== -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just add a simple condition, `str !== '0.0.0.0' && str !== '255.255.255.255'` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Comment: You should use this regex ==> [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/4COnWv/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

`^(?!0\.0\.0\.0|255\.255\.255\.255)((((2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(((2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})))$`

- `^` - start
- `(?!0\.0\.0\.0|255\.255\.255\.255)` - not 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.255
- `((2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})` - 0-255
- `(((2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}` - 0-255 followed by a full stop, three times
- `(((2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}))` - 0-255
- `$` - end

[image: Regular expression visualisation]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UeTGZZu8jbMb_hjJ)

Comment: The `[0-9]{1,2}` parts should probably be changed to `[1-9]?[0-9]` if you don't want something like `2.3.04.43` to work (ie the `04` bit).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a check before using regex

```
return  str !== '0.0.0.0' && str !== '255.255.255.255'  ? regex.test(str) : false
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to do is test the inputString wtih my regex and parse it to true or false. So, I need regex, not JS modification. I edited my question and please check it. Thank you

Comment: @JaehanPark there are two other answer which already addressed regex solutions you can use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/^(?!0.0.0.0)(?!255.255.255.255)(?:\d|\d\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|\d\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$/g`.